# Kivy / Python-for-android : Build.py fails to build an android package apk

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, ubuntu-11.10, kivy

I try for many days to build a simple android package using kivy and python for android. Unfortunately, I've spent many hours trying to solve all the issues but I still cannot do it. I hope you guys help me out because you are my last hope before throwing my laptop off the window...

I have succeeded to build the distribution directory using only the kivy module.So the output folder /dist/default has all the necessary files (I hope) in order to build my apk. The command that I use to build the apk, according to the example in the docs is the following:

```
sudo ./build.py --dir ~/mount_point/kivy --name "Myapp" --package org.mytest.myapp --version 1.0 installd
```

What I get is:

> An error occured while calling ~/android-sdk-linux/tools/android update
>   Your PATH must include android tools.

I have already inserted in the `bashrc` the appropriate exports. So if i run the following:

```
~/android-sdk-linux/tools/android update
```

I get:

> Error: Missing object name for verb 'update'.
>   [Continues with usage details...]

I don't know what to do and I cannot find anything in the Internet. If you need more details just ask me to provide. My OS is UBUNTU 11.10. Thanks!

Comment: You can try asking on python-for-android on google groups. I have had a lot of problems too with it, it's there that you can get the most help :)

Comment: I have posted the question there as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, as a linux noob I didn't know that I had to export the required variables to the root's .bashrc file, as I didn't know that there are different bash profiles for each user, and then run the command as a root. As I did that the build script worked as it should.

Answer (score 2):

To make it easier for new comers or lazy people like me who don't have the patience to setup the `Android sdk`, `Android ndk` and `python for android`, along with the appropriate paths and settings; there is now this Virtual Box [Image](http://kivy.org/#download)(932MB scroll down at the end of the page) with everything pre-setup on Ubuntu. One can use it to easily make a apk in 5 simple steps using the python for android build chain.

Answer (score 1):

Python for android try to upgrade you project by doing the command (8 or 14 depending your configuration):

```
android update project -p . -t android-8
```

The message indicate that android binary is not found in the PATH. If you correctly set, then show the exact error message that appear before this one, or the message appearing when you manually update the project.